# Redis is not showing as a dependency in Elastic apm

Tags: go, redis, gorilla, elastic-apm, go-redis

I am using Elastic apm to monitor my go application.I use gorilla mux framework and redis db.I have  integrated elastic apm with my code but I am not sure how to  add redis as a dependency in elastic apm.Can someone help me with this  please?

I have tried various ways to do the same.But nothing is working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.